# Libgdx return moving image back to original position

Tags: java, libgdx

I have this image displayed on the screen from an array (at 50,100) where when the user touches that image, it moves to a different position on the screen (100,200), I want to know how can the user touch that same image again and it moves back to the original position.

```
        final Image img = pic.get(0);
        pic.get(0).addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                System.out.println("CLICKED!!!");
                img.addAction(Actions.moveTo(300,700));
            }
        });
   }
```

Comment: Not an answer : you can save current position of image into prevX and prevY and on touch event or click event move it to new coordinates, not sure if it helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the previous Position.If the image by clicked not on the previous position go back to the previous Position else go to the new position:

```
final Image img = pic.get(0);
final float prevX = img.getX(), prevY = img.getY();

img.addListener(new ClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        System.out.println("CLICKED!!!");
        if(img.getX() != prevX || img.getY() != prevY)
            img.addAction(Actions.moveTo(prevX, prevY));
        else
            img.addAction(Actions.moveTo(300,700));
    }
});
```